# Angular ng-show is not showing the element in the view

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to implement a simple Angular ng-show in my code but I cannot seem to make it work. I am attaching the code below.

***HTML***

```
  <div ng-repeat="question in data.questions track by $index" ng-if="question.visible" class="slide">

  <md-radio-group ng-model="question.selectedAnswer" ng-if="vm.showSliderChecker">
    <md-radio-button ng-repeat="ans in question.answer track by $index" ng-value="ans._id"
                     ng-click="radioBtnClick({qId: question._id, ansId: ans._id})">{{::ans.description}}
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>




  <div class="wrapper" ng-show="vm.showSliderChecker">
 <div class="toggle_radio">
<input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option" >

<label for="first_toggle" class="widthEighth" ng-repeat="ans in question.answer track by $index" ng-value="ans._id"
                     ng-click="radioBtnClick({qId: question._id, ansId: ans._id}); showSliderClickedMessage()"><p> {{$index+1}} </p></label>


  </div> 

</div>

</div>
```

***Angular Controller***
    vm.checkSliderForDisplay = checkSliderForDisplay;

```
function initController(){
   checkSliderForDisplay();
}

function checkSliderForDisplay() {
  if($stateParams.testType === "Stress_management"){
        vm.showSliderChecker = true;

        console.log("The value of slider checker is true and here's proof ----> ");
        console.log(vm.showSliderChecker);
      }
      else{
        vm.showSliderChecker = false;
        console.log("Alas, the slider checker is just a lot of false advertising and nothing more.");
        console.log(vm.showSliderChecker);
      }
}

initController();
```

Now here's the problem:

The console logs are showing on the console but the both the divs stay hidden. I have looked for a solution on this website and tried a bunch of combinations thinking I am missing some minute detail but I just can seem to make it work.

Comment: Can you add your whole html? Specially where the controller/view and ng-app sections are defined?

Comment: If you add `{{vm.showSliderChecker}}` to your view , does it show the value correct? I see you are using `vm`, did you 'bind' your controller using `controllerAs : vm` or `var vm = this;`?

Comment: Let me do it @Juan 

Also, I have done that already, daan.desmedt .. 

Let edit my answer and post the new html there.

Comment: Are you using Controller as syntax? Doesn't seem to be the case. Try removing "vm." from your expressions.

Comment: I am using the controllerAs syntax and it is defined where I have done the routing config. I dont think removing it will improve my code.

Comment: Can you show your controller routing config for that view? Also where are you calling the init Controller function from? I would say that is from inside the controller itself, so you should be doing "this.showSliderChecker = false" instead of referring to it by "vm"

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the Controller As synstax vm is the name you can refer to the controller in the scope.

If your code is running in a different closure, like from the controller constructor, you may need to refer to it differently.

Looks like that piece of code is called in the Controller constructor so "vm" won't be a defined variable there. You should use "this" instead:

```
function checkSliderForDisplay() {
  if(this.testType === "Stress_management"){
    this.showSliderChecker = true;

    console.log("The value of slider checker is true and here's proof ----> ");
    console.log(this.showSliderChecker);
  }
  else{
    this.showSliderChecker = false;
    console.log("Alas, the slider checker is just a lot of false advertising and nothing more.");
    console.log(this.showSliderChecker);
  }
}
```

If you add `"use strict";` at the top of your js files you should get some warning.

Comment: Hey. I already am using "use strict" at the top and I am not calling it from the controller constructor. As a matter of fact, I am using the John Papa Style Guidelines to the last details and it is a pretty biiig project with lots of modules so I dont think I will be able to show you everything, simply coz its too much.

Comment: Can you use a pluging like Batarang and show us what is on the scope for the ng-if elements?